# Correctly usage of vars in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, alert

How can I use these both scripts on the same page? I'm new in js but I'm pretty sure that I can't use these same vars to make both scripts work correctly after an error (or even more if I want to). "Swal" is a customized alert.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
         var url = new URL(window.location.href);
         var error = url.searchParams.get("error");

         if(error==1) swal("Oops...", "Primeiro você deve escolher uma foto. Clique no botão 'Alterar Foto'.", "error");
    }
</script>

<script>
    window.onload = function(){
         var url = new URL(window.location.href);
         var error = url.searchParams.get("error");

         if(error==2) swal("Formato Inválido", "Por favor, escolha uma imagem no formato 'PNG' ou 'JPG'.", "warning");
         }
</script>
```

Comment: In this particular case, why don't you simply put another `else if (...)` into the first script without repeating all the identical code before it?

Comment: Your problem is not with the `url` and `error` variables being duplicated (they are local to their respective function, that's fine), but rather both scripts writing to the `window.onload` property. It would work if you were using `window.addEventListener("load", function(){…});`

Comment: I am trying to make it work with addEventListener, but nothing yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge them together like :

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var url = new URL(window.location.href);
        var error = url.searchParams.get("error");

        if(error==1) {
             swal("Oops...", "Primeiro você deve escolher uma foto. Clique no botão 'Alterar Foto'.", "error");
        } else if(error==2) {
             swal("Formato Inválido", "Por favor, escolha uma imagem no formato 'PNG' ou 'JPG'.", "warning");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**NOTE:** It will be better to use `addEventListener` to attach events instead of `onload`.

Comment: I can't make it work with addEventListener, even copying your code.

Comment: nevermind, I have made some changes and now it works, thanks for the merge and event listener tips!

Comment: Glad I could help brother, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the old onload/onclick, use addEventListener and/or attachEvent if you need to support < IE9.